R Session Aborted
I am running the code, but there have been frequent R crash reconstruction tasks recently.
Any help in resolving these errors is much appreciated.
I am working with:
MacOS Sonoma 14.5
R 4.4.0
RStudio 2024.04.0+735

Thanks

the code is
{
library(openxlsx) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggsci) 
library(gridExtra) 
library(ggpubr) 
s=read.xlsx("PPCPs sum.xlsx","sources total",colNames = T) 

ggboxplot(subset(s,s$Type=="Water"&s$Seasons=="Winter"&s$Chem=="IBU"), x="Sources",y="Conc", color = "Sources", palette = "jco", add = "jitter") + 
  theme()+ 
  stat_compare_means( aes(group=Sources), method="kruskal.test", label = "p.signif")
}

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both R and RStudio, and R is installed fine (I can open and work on the R console).

There's no way to help without seeing the code that's causing the crash.  Can you share the code that's causing it?

It looks like a startup error. Make sure that you are not automatically loading a .Rdata file which causes the problem.

@tospig, the code is {library(openxlsx)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggpubr)
s=read.xlsx("PPCPs sum.xlsx","sources total",colNames = T)
ggboxplot(subset(s,s$Type=="Water"&s$Seasons=="Winter"&s$Chem=="IBU"), x="Sources",y="Conc",
color = "Sources",
palette = "jco", add = "jitter") +
theme()+
stat_compare_means(
aes(group=Sources),
method="kruskal.test",
label = "p.signif")} but the crush could be happen in everyday, not only this code

@DavoOZ I encountered this problem when I was running the code. Sometimes, after running for half an hour, this problem suddenly appeared, not from the beginning. And I can't understand how to automatically load .Rdata files.

Can you edit your queston and put the code in there please, rather than as a comment?
